# How to debug renderer process of electron-forge react-typescript?

Tags: typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron, electron-forge

I've used electron forge to generate an app base on react-typescript template. I've written some vscode debug configs for that app. But I've just could debug for Main process, Renderer is missing. I've installed debugger for chrome extension and used it before. I wonder what am I missing in the config ?

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Electron: Main",
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--remote-debugging-port=9223",
                "."
            ],
            "windows": {
                "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win.cmd"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Electron: Renderer",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9223,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "timeout": 30000
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Electron: All",
            "configurations": [
                "Electron: Main",
                "Electron: Renderer"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is way after the fact, but I wanted to answer in case anyone else is struggling with this problem like I was all day today.

After reading a key piece of info from [matsu's blog](https://blog.matsu.io/debug-electron-vscode):

> Go to main.js and comment out this line:
>
> mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
>
> Remote debugging doesn't work
>   with multiple DevTools clients. We'll use the debugger in VS Code
>   instead of Electron's DevTools.

--

Some (all?) of the electron-forge templates open the Chrome dev tools at startup. A limitation of Chrome / Electron is that only one connection to a debugger of any kind is supported (confirmed in the [response from MSFT here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46062)). We just need to comment that line out.

In your main.js (or index.ts or whatever):

```
 // Open the DevTools.
  if (isDevMode) {
    await installExtension(REACT_DEVELOPER_TOOLS);
    //mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools(); <--- comment this out
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copied your **launch.json**, then write some code and set break point.
The test code is placed at the end of **app.tsx**:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    let x = 0;            //break point here
    console.log(x);
}, 3000);
```

The break point works fine.

Another change I made in the **launch.json** is:

```
"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron-forge-vscode-win",
"runtimeArgs": [
    ".",  //swap this line and the next line
    "--remote-debugging-port=9223"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

In `package.json` add new script

```
"debug": "electron-forge start --vscode"
```

and then add below config in `.vscode/ launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Electron Main",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "debug"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have used the above config for my ReactJS with Webpack project.

Comment: The question is asking how to debug the renderer process -- not the main process ("Electron Main").